# Why does Google say I have a different IP to my PHP script?

Tags: php, ip

### Overview

In the process of trying to whitelist my work PC IP for a website so that I can see the debugging errors, I'm trying to establish my IP.

---

### Code/Research

My [Google Search](https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=off&q=what+is+my+ip+address) says that my IP is:

> **32.xx.24.180**
>
> *Your public IP address*

Running `curl canhazip.com` from the terminal on the computer I'm trying to whitelist displays:

> *`94.xxx.108.175`*

*Visiting* `canhazip.com` displays:

> *`165.xxx.80.120`*

This is my `PHP/HTML` code:

```
REMOTE_ADDR = <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ?>
HTTP_CLIENT_IP = <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ?>
```

The output is:

> *`REMOTE_ADDR = 165.xxx.80.120`*
> *`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = 32.xxx.24.182`*
> *`HTTP_CLIENT_IP =`*

---

### Issue/Question

The closest IP from my PHP script correlating to Google is the `$_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]` value, although the second and final sets of digits are incorrect.

- If I want to whitelist my PC's IP, what is the `$_SEVER` variable that I should match up to?
- Why is Google's IP different to any of the `$_SERVER` variables received by the PHP code?

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For. There's a server between your server and the internet. Do a `curl canhazip.com` **from the computer you want to whitelist** to see what IP it presents to the public Internet, which is what you'd want to whitelist (assuming the website you're trying to whitelist on is also on the public Internet).

Comment: you have a proxy of some sort. if you want to whitelist, you have to use the IP that google sees. whitelisting the private/internal one is pointless - google goes off the actual tcp-level IP, not whatever random garbage is inserted into the http headers.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. I ran the command and it resulted with `94.xxx.108.175`. The whitelisting is done in `PHP`, so which of the `$_SERVER` variables do I need to compare to that value?

Comment: If you are at work, maybe you have a reverse proxy installed.